# why is spark streaming called near real time?

Tags: pyspark, real-time, near-real-time

I know that spark streaming uses micro batches to process the data, but the processing is done in less than a second in some cases. My question is "Can't it be called pure real time processing rather than near real time processing in that senario?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that we can only talk about real-time for metrics, alerts and optimization when data is gathered and directly pushed to a dashboard or system, without any kind of ETL process, the purpose of real time is, mainly, the speed.

Whenever there is a process with batches that extracts historical trending or benchmarking, despite it takes less than a seccond, then is not real-time but is close to it, that's because they talk about near real time.

So, to answer your question, I'd say that no, is near real time because you are batching and processing.

I hope it helps.

Juan

Comment: I've just asked our Big Data expert (he works just in my right) and he says that in the Big Data Spark Streaming is considered near real time because his precision is close to milliseconds and with frameworks like Storm or the new Spark (Structured Streamming) you work on a nanosecond precision which is what purist in Big Data would call real time.

Answer (score 2):

Spark Streaming divides the data stream into batches of X seconds called Dstreams, which internally is a sequence of RDDs, one for each batch interval. Each RDD contains the records received during the batch interval.since its process in small batches called near real time not real time.